# Is XWT still supported?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, xwt

I see that in the new e4 repo (http://download.eclipse.org/e4/downloads/drops/S-0.15-201401152200/repository/) there are no xwt plugins...

Does eclipse still encourage developers to use XWT for RCP? Or is it deprecated?
I couldn't find any documentation about it.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That repository only contains the Eclipse e4 tools.

Look in the main Eclipse repository (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna for Luna) for XWT